# php slim how to file upload using eloquent?

Tags: php, eloquent, slim

I'm trying to upload an image and im using postman and the image is not being inserted in the database

this is the error

Any Suggestions on what i should do ?

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'image' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `images` (`image`) values ())
```

here is the route

```
$app->post('/images', function($request, $response, $args) {
  $data = $request->getUploadedFiles();
  $image = new Image();
  $image->image = $data['image'];
  $image->save();

  return $this->response->write($image->toJson());
});
```

here is the postman page

[image]

and here are the headers

[image]

Comment: are you sure postman is properly sending the image in the request?

Comment: Can you share how you're using postman to test the api call.

Comment: @bos570 i just edited thats what it looks like

Comment: Can yo share the headers please?

Comment: @bos570 i just updated it take a look now , thanks :)

Comment: Uncheck the Content-Type header and send the request. See if that works.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

You are setting the Model image property to an **object** of type `\Psr\Http\Message\UploadedFileInterface` instead of a **string**. The Model does not know how to handle the object.

The Slim `$request->getUploadedFiles()` returns an object of type `\Psr\Http\Message\UploadedFileInterface` and **not a string**.

**Solution**

To access the image data, first we need to get the **stream**:

```
$data = $request->getUploadedFiles();
$uploadedImage = $data['image'];
$uploadedImageStream = $uploadedImage->getStream();
```

Now that we have the **stream**, we can read from it **chunks** just like we would from a file. However, we are just going to fetch all the data at once and set it to the Model property:

```
$image->image = $uploadedImageStream->getContents();
```

Comment: thanks but i got this `Call to a member function getStream() on null`

Comment: I suspect the image keys are not matching. Check your postman Body keys.